# Form isn't submitted after checking the input

Tags: javascript, jquery

In a form a user among other things, fills an integer. When he submit the form, I want to check that number. If the `number < 100` then the form to be submitted normally. If not, then I want to show him a confirmation window and if selects Ok then the form to be submitted.

```js
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var quantity = $('#quantity').val(); // Get the user input.
  var quantityToCompare = 100; //the number to compare

  if (quantity < quantityToCompare) {
    console.log("Submit the form");
    $('form').submit();
  } else {
    console.log(quantity + " is bigger from " + quantityToCompare);

    var confirmation = confirm("Do you want to continue with the submit ?");
    if (confirmation) {
      console.log("submitting now ...");
      $('form').submit();
    } else {
      console.log("Clicked Cancel");
    }
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <form id="form" method="post" role="form">

      <label class="col-md-1 control-label">Quantity</label>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <input id="quantity" type="number" class="form-control" name="quantity" required>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <button type="submit" name="formAction" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have 2 problems. If the user fills a `number < 100` then I get an error `too much recursion` and if the user fills a bigger number and then the pop up window is constantly opening and I can't submit the form.

What I am missing?

Comment: You are overwriting the `submit` event and cause an endless loop until a stackoverflow ;) just have a look at the console (F12)

Comment: Why would you have `$('form').submit();` inside the form submit?

Comment: My thinking was.. 1. Prevent the submit 2. Check the condition you want 3. if the number is smaller continue with the submission. 4. If not ask the user to confirm the input. 5. if he clicks ok continue with the submit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To submit the form based on a condition inside a jQuery `submit` event handler, you have to call the **native** submit event, otherwise the event handler is just called again, and the form is prevented from submitting

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var quantity = $('#quantity').val(); // Get the user input.
  var quantityToCompare = 100; //the number to compare

  if (quantity < quantityToCompare) {
    this.submit();
  } else {
    var confirmation = confirm("Do you want to continue with the submit ?");
    if (confirmation) {
      this.submit();
    } else {
      console.log("Clicked Cancel");
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`e.preventDefault();` in your submit handler is preventing to submit. do it only when you don't want allow for submit.

**EDIT**

In additon:
Even if you will call `$('form').submit()` that will call the same event recursively and will be again prevented and will call recursively again and again. so, in the conditions you are nit interested to submit, call `e.preventDefault();` only in those block and remove the `$('form').submit()`, you are already in submit event because it was submitted.

Answer (score 0):

$('form').submit(); 
this code calls recursively.

Comment: yes, and every time preventDefault is preventing at first

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `form submit` inside the `form submit` function .its produce the loop effect .that why its give alert again and again.Do your function when from submitted successfully

```js
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var quantity = $('#quantity').val(); // Get the user input.
  var quantityToCompare = 100; //the number to compare

  if (quantity < quantityToCompare) {
    console.log("Submit the form");
    //do your function
  } else {
    console.log(quantity + " is bigger from " + quantityToCompare);
    var confirmation = confirm("Do you want to continue with the submit ?");
    if (confirmation) {
      console.log("submitting now ...");
      //do your function
    } else {
      console.log("Clicked Cancel");
    }
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <form id="form" method="post" role="form">

      <label class="col-md-1 control-label">Quantity</label>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <input id="quantity" type="number" class="form-control" name="quantity" required>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <button type="submit" name="formAction" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#submit').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var quantity = $('#quantity').val(); // Get the user input.
  var quantityToCompare = 100; //the number to compare
  var submitFlag = true;
  if (quantity < quantityToCompare) {
    submitFlag = true;
  } else {
    submitFlag = false;
  }

  if (!submitFlag) {
    var confirmation = confirm("Do you want to continue with the submit ?");
    if (confirmation) {
      submitFlag = true;
    } else {
      console.log("Clicked Cancel");
    }
  }

  if (submitFlag)
    console.log("SUBMIT"); // $("#form").submit();
  else
    return false;

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <form id="form" method="post" role="form" action='http://www.google.com'>

      <label class="col-md-1 control-label">Quantity</label>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <input id="quantity" type="number" class="form-control" name="quantity" required>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <button name="formAction" id="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```